# У меня в футере 5 картинок,я хочу чтобы при нажатии на них посредине экрана сверху высвечивалась информация.К каждой картинка отдельная

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня в футере 5 картинок,я хочу чтобы при нажатии на них посредине экрана сверху высвечивалась информация.К каждой картинка отдельная.Но при нажатии на них ничего не происходит,что делать?Вот мой код:

```
<div id="desc"></div>

    <style>
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}
.content {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.footer {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
img {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 50px;
  width: 70px;
  display: inline-block;
}
#desc {
  text-align: center;  
}
.image_cart {
  display: block;
}

.image_cart img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 150px;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.image_cart:not(.active) .description {
  display: none;
  font-size: x-large;
  text-align: center;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

#somedesc {
  font-size: x-large;
  text-align: center;
}
}</style> 

    <script>


$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.image_cart').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    if ( $(this).hasClass("active") )
      $("#desc").html($(this).find(".description").html());
    else
      $("#desc").html("");


});
    $('body').css('background', 'url(file:///C:/Users/naza1/Desktop/jQuery/images/1.jpg )')
  });


</script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="content">Чтооо?</div>

  <div class="footer">
    <img src="file:///C:/Users/naza1/Desktop/jQuery/images/1.jpg" alt />
    <img src="file:///C:/Users/naza1/Desktop/jQuery/images/2.png" alt />
    <img src="file:///C:/Users/naza1/Desktop/jQuery/images/3.png" alt />
    <img src="file:///C:/Users/naza1/Desktop/jQuery/images/4.png" alt />
    <img src="file:///C:/Users/naza1/Desktop/jQuery/images/5.png"alt />

  </div>

</div>



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="image_cart">
  <img src="file:///C:/Users/naza1/Desktop/jQuery/images/2.png" descSelector="#somedesc" alt="No image" class="img-2" />
  <div class="description">
    <h3>Лев</h3>
    <p>Вид хищных млекопитающих, один из четырёх представителей рода пантер, относящегося к подсемейству больших кошек в составе семейства кошачьих. Наряду с тигром — самая крупная из ныне живущих кошек, масса некоторых самцов может достигать 250 кг.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="image_cart">
  <img src="file:///C:/Users/naza1/Desktop/jQuery/images/3.png" descSelector="#somedesc" alt="No image" class="img-3" />
  <div class="description">
    <h3>Барс</h3>
    <p>Бла-бла-бла</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="image_cart">
  <img src="file:///C:/Users/naza1/Desktop/jQuery/images/4.png" descSelector="#somedesc" alt="No image" class="img-4" />
  <div class="description">
    <h3>Тигр</h3>
    <p>Бла-бла-бла</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="image_cart">
  <img src="file:///C:/Users/naza1/Desktop/jQuery/images/5.png" descSelector="#somedesc" alt="No image" class="img-5" />
  <div class="description">
    <h3>Пума</h3>
    <p>Бла-бла-бла</p>
  </div>
</div>


<div id="somedesc" class="hidden">
  <p><b>Лев</b></p>Вид хищных млекопитающих, один из четырёх представителей рода пантер, относящегося к подсемейству больших кошек в составе семейства кошачьих. Наряду с тигром — самая крупная из ныне живущих кошек, масса некоторых самцов может достигать
  250 кг.</div>
```